# making a call through vb.net using skype api

Tags: vb.net, skype

1. how do i include the skype libraries in my vb.net app?
2. how do i make a call on skype through vb,net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype provides a COM API that can be used from VB.NET.  For more info on using COM from VB.NET see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x66s8zcd.aspx

The Skype API documentation can be found at:

https://developer.skype.com/Docs/ApiDoc

And, although not in VB.NET there is good example of how to use the Skype API in the [SEHE AKA Skype Event Handler Example](http://saveontelephonebills.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=2).  It is written in C#, but the same principles apply to VB.NET, just slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This is in C# but its easy enough to convert to VB [using the Skype API](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/38-windows/203-recording-skype.html)

Answer (score 1):

here is the code to place a call on skype with vb.net, inculding declaration.

```
Imports SKYPE4COMLib
Public class form 1
Public WithEvents skype As New SKYPE4COMLib.Skype
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  'check if the skype client is running
  If Not skype.Client.IsRunning Then
        skype.Client.Start()
    End If
end sub
'use a button or other control to place a call to the test account of skype
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    skype.PlaceCall("echo123")
End Sub
```

to place a call to somone else just replace echo123, dont forget the "quotes"