# Is it possible to write ASP .NET website which will call a telephone number by Skype or an alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, voip, skype

I need to create a crm website available from Windows browser which can call a number(telephone number) in a text field via Skype or alternative to Skype.

Is that even possible that HTML website? Is calling from Skype or alternative must be done on a clients computer by **standalone Form application?**

I will be calling only real phone numbers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020629/making-a-call-through-vb-net-using-skype-api

Check before posting new question

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee The link refers to COM component which can be used in WinForms I do not know if it can be added to the website via ASP .NET

Comment: @Yoda: Yes, in the backend, but then you call server side, not client side.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have probably the most stupidest question for someone who develops web applications. At my school they never showed us where to or how actually upload on a public server such site so IT IS in the real web on a domain. Is there any tutorial for that.

Comment: Just google for free webhosting. Microsoft's Azure is a good posibility for ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very easy solution when just using html.

When you create a hyperlink starting with `tel:` (instead of `http:` or `mailto:`) it will open the default calling program, possibly Skype.

```
<a href="tel:+1123456789">Call me!</a>
```

Comment: You'd be advised not to include literal spaces in the URI. Prefer `tel:+1123456`

Comment: Generally with URIs, it's valid to include the space directly, but it can cause problems when they are misinterpreted as the end of URI (the space being the only way to detect it in some contexts), so we generally prefer `%20`. In the case of `tel` though, RFC 3966 says "even though ITU-T E.123 [E.123] recommends the use of space characters as visual separators in printed telephone numbers, 'tel' URIs MUST NOT use spaces in visual separators to avoid excessive escaping." (§ 5.1.1).

Comment: @Jon: that makes totally sense.

Answer (score 2):

There is a company called RebTel which offers a similar service to Skype, but they provide an SDK for access to calling called sinch.

Check out https://developer.rebtel.com/

Note that this will cost money.

Answer (score 1):

This is something different from a real phone call. When we do a hyper-link, this simply invokes an associated calling program and that's it.

But if we really want to call from our computer, then we need a solution similar to a IVR Card from dialogic or similar hardware sellers where we connect our telephone wire RJ11 to our system and have a program running which can make calls through that line.

We can also have a GSM Modem connected to the system with capability for making such calls, though I haven't used them except for sending/receiving SMS.

The other option is to have a SIP Server which will have such phone provisions and will be able to receive digital voice and convert to analog and vice versa.

So when we have such a link we need a program (and/or hardware setup) to really make such calls.